# Getting the name of all existing documents in a fluid server

Tags: fluid-framework

I would like to create a landing page displaying the name of all the existent documents in the fluid server, so I can click on each and it redirects to the corresponding fluid document.

Is there any way to retrieve the name of all existing documents in a fluid server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible today. When you create or load a Fluid container, you provide the ID to the Fluid service, so the expectation is that you track that ID external to the Fluid service. That said, this is something we're looking at for the future, so I encourage you to open an issue on the FluidFramework repo with your scenario.